# How to install MSVS (Microsoft Visual Studio) 2008 Express to C: and D: drives (not to C: D: E: as it offers)

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I have drives C: and D: which are backed up regularly.
E: is not backed up, but it has most free space (120 Gb instead of 80 Gb on D:).

When I specified path D:\Program Files... installing C# from 2008 Express ISO, i got a message:

Disk space requirements: C: 887 MB and D: 80Mb and E: 229 MB

How to evade disk E: use?
What is it used for? Maybe for temp data only?

E: will not be backed up and I will fail MSVS restoring :(

I have found some ways to do it, but they are too dumb or hacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of E: in this case will be for temporary files. The VS installer installers to the system drive (.NET and VC++ etc. runtimes, with VS2010 and later also Windows/.NET SDKs) and to the target drive (VS itself and other tools).

But the installer also needs working space, and for this it automatically uses the drive with the most free space.

Comment: Depending on Richard's status, it can't be lie. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 other ways, but they are useless now and somewhat strange:

1. Copy as many video to drive E: to decrease its free space. Installer will use D: then.
2. (For example, on Windows XP) "delete" drive E: and copy msvs installer to D: (deleting it after) or to DVD. After that we can safely restore it via Administration icon of Control Panel.

But judging by Richard's answer, it is not needed. I saw - no new files appeared on drive E: after installation. So for lesser fragmentation it is better to use E:.